# Jordan Form of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to find a matrix $P$ such that $J=P^{-1}AP$, where $J$ is the Jordan Form of the matrix:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
-1&2&2\\
-3&4&3\\
1&-1&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The characteristic polynomial is: $p(\lambda)=(\lambda-1)^3$, and a eigenvector for $A-I$ is $\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 1 \\-1 \end{pmatrix}$. Now, how can I find other $2$ vectors?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: See this example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your fault is, that there is a second eigenvector, the Jordan normal form is $$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$
You can find a second eigenvector $w$ and a vector $z$ such that $(A-I)z=w$.

Answer (score 3):

Call the eigenvector you found, $v$. Then you need $w$ such that $(A-I)w=v$, and $x$ such that $(A-I)x=w$.

EDIT: Sorry, I was taking it for granted that the eigenspace for 
$\lambda=1$ is 1-dimensional, but in fact it's 2-dimensional. That is, the matrix $A-I$ has nullity 2, so you can find a second linearly independent eigenvector, call it $u$. Then you have to find $w$ such that $(A-I)w$ is in the span of $u$ and $v$.

More edit: Julian noticed this 2 minutes before I did.

Comment: maybe I am mistaken, but my problem is that I can not find $w$ because the system has no solution. Obviously I have an error, but I can not see it. thanks

Comment: @Hiperion: We can't tell you what your error is unless you show us your working.